# How to set correct sizes for columns in layout - PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to build the following window on PySide:

[image]

My solution for this was to see it as 3 columns and implemented as such:

```
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.resize(200, 500)
l = pg.GraphicsLayout(border='ff0000')

# The Overall layout consists of three columns with widths in the ratio of 1/8, 2/8, 5/8

# =======   col 1
vb = l.addViewBox(col=0, colspan=1, border='00ff00', lockAspect=True, enableMouse=False, invertY=True)
img = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(QtGui.QPixmap('heart.png')))
vb.addItem(img)
vb.scaleBy(10)

# =======   col 2
top_label = "Percent"
bottom_label = "85"
l_labels = l.addLayout(col=1, colspan=1)
l_labels.addLabel(top_label, row=0, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=1, size='30pt', bold=True)
l_labels.addLabel(bottom_label, row=2, col=0, rowspan=4, colspan=1, size='200pt', color='606060')
l_labels.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 100) 

# =======   col 3
hr_plot = l.addPlot(col=2, colspan=6)
hr_plot.showGrid(x=False, y=True)
pen = pg.mkPen(color='#39e4f8', width=4)

hr_plot.plot(data, pen=pen,
             symbol='o',
             symbolPen=pen,
             symbolBrush='#FFFFFF',
             symbolSize=16)

win.addItem(l)
```

However, that only results in the following layout:
[image]

My main issue is the following:

**How can I adjust the width of the first column (possibly by adjusting the width of "ViewBox" or by any other means)?**

**Trying QGridLayout:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `QLayout` instead of `pyqtgraph.GraphicsLayout`: [pyqtgraph-documentation](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/qtcrashcourse.html#qwidgets-and-layouts)

there you can set stretchFactors. Here a rewrite of your code using  QGridLayout (only widgets can be added to layout, so `LabelItem` is replaced by QLabel):

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

width = 500
height = 200
fontsize1 = width/40
fontsize2 = width/15
scalefactor = width/50

w = QtGui.QWidget()
w.resize(width, height)

# =======   widgets col 1
img = QtGui.QLabel()      
pm = QtGui.QPixmap('del_w.xpm')
iw = pm.width()/scalefactor
ih = pm.height()/scalefactor
npm = pm.scaled(iw,ih)          # scaled pixmap
img.setPixmap(npm)

# =======   widgets col 2
top_label = QtGui.QLabel('Percent') #, size='30pt', bold=True)
top_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
top_label.setStyleSheet('font-size: {}pt; font-style: bold'.format(fontsize1))
bottom_label = QtGui.QLabel('85')
bottom_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
bottom_label.setStyleSheet('font-size: {}pt; font-style: bold; color: 606060'.format(fontsize2))

# =======   widgets col 3
hr_plot = pg.PlotWidget()
hr_plot.showGrid(x=False, y=True)
pen = pg.mkPen(color='#39e4f8', width=4)

hr_plot.plot(data, pen=pen,
         symbol='o',
         symbolPen=pen,
         symbolBrush='#FFFFFF',
         symbolSize=4)

# ======= gridlayout
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)

# ======= add widgets to layout
layout.addWidget(img,0,0)
layout.addWidget(top_label,0,1)
layout.addWidget(bottom_label,1,1,2,1)  # rowspan = 2, colspan = 1
layout.addWidget(hr_plot, 0, 2,5,1) # rowspan = 5, colspan = 1

# ======= set stretchfactors for column
layout.setColumnStretch(0,1)
layout.setColumnStretch(1,2)
layout.setColumnStretch(2,5)

w.showMaximized()
app.exec()
```

Edit:

i can reproduce your issue with a pixmap of 500 x 500 px. In your example the pixmap and the fontsize seem to be to large, so they require more space than you want to give them.

> Any widgets that are allocated more space than their maximum size are
>   allocated the maximum size space they require.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

you should play with fontsize and scaling the pixmap (example added in the code above)
after scaling the pixmap and reducing the fontsize i get the following widget:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried that approach earlier today but I get a worse results. I edited the question above and added the result from using QGridLayout to the bottom of it.